# MFC Handling messages from a separate window

Tags: c++, mfc, window, message

I have created a window with some controls and currently work with it. On some message I open a separate class as

```
inPUT* ppFrame = new inPUT(hmm::n,hmm::yDim);
ppFrame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

and input some data there, save it somewhere in that class and close it. 
Question: how can I get that data back to the original class ON_WM_CLOSE()of ppFrame not an original class for example, when I know that the data was already received by ppFrame

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to pass in a pointer to the original class. Then set the data when handling the WM_CLOSE message. Assuming the original class is handling the message that creates this other window (and the original class lives longer than the inPUT window):

```
inPUT* ppFrame = new inPUT(hmm::n,hmm::yDim, this);
```

on WM_CLOSE you can do the following using that **this** pointer:

```
OrigPtr->SetMyData(/*data you have*/);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I have similar ideas, but I thought there was a way to handle messages from the other class by the main one (not a parent). THANKS SO MUCH AGAIN!